# Internet Explorer and post_max_size

Tags: forms, file-upload, internet-explorer-9, php

Been having a problem with IE9, go figure... I try to upload files and although post_max_size is set to 30M when I alert the result of php call ini_get('post_max_size') in firefox, in Internet explorer it shows it is set to 8M...??? I f'n hate Internet explorer, but I must somehow get it to work. Can anyone offer any sort of answer to what might be happening? I don't see the need to post code, but if you need anything, let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with post_max_size at least as it pertains to godaddy.com is that you must name your php.ini file php5.ini; also, if you import your php.ini file and simply change it's name in your hosting server, the section called session.save_path in your .ini folder will likely read the wrong tmp location for your sessions, so you must either create your own secure directory in your filesystem or figure out where you are supposed to store them and type in that path. Hope this helps someone out there.